# WebRTC does not connect to the local subscriber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to create a screen demo between 2 conversation partners via WebRTC. But for some reason my connection has a status of "new". I am using React as frontend and Express JS as signaling server. The demo is sent only by the user who initiated the call.
Here is my frontend code:

```
socket.on("add-iceCandidate", (data) => {
    peerConnections.current[data.clientID]?.addIceCandidate(
      new RTCIceCandidate(data.iceCandidate)
    );
  })

  socket.on('call', async (data) => {

    if (data.clientID in peerConnections) {
      return warn("Client already in peer connections list")
    }

    peerConnections.current[data.clientID] = new RTCPeerConnection();

peerConnections.current[data.clientID].onicecandidate = event => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        socket.emit("send-ice", {
          clientID: data.clientID,
          iceCandidate: event.candidate.candidate,
        });
      }
    }

    peerConnections.current[data.clientID].ontrack = (event) => {
      const [remoteStream] = event.streams;
      videoRef.current.srcObject = remoteStream;
    }

    localMediaStream.current?.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      peerConnections.current[data.clientID].addTrack(track, localMediaStream.current);
    });

    if (data.offer) {
      const offer = await peerConnections.current[data.clientID].createOffer();
      await peerConnections.current[data.clientID].setLocalDescription(offer);

      const roomOffer = {
        offer: {
          type: offer.type,
          sdp: offer.sdp
        }
      }

      socket.emit("add-offer", {
        clientID: data.clientID,
        offer: roomOffer
      })
    }

  })

socket.on('add-offer', async (data) => {
    await peerConnections.current[data.clientID]?.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.offer.offer))
    const answer = await peerConnections.current[data.clientID].createAnswer();
    await peerConnections.current[data.clientID].setLocalDescription(answer);

    const roomAnswer = {
      answer: {
        type: answer.type,
        sdp: answer.sdp
      }
    }

    socket.emit("add-answer", {
      clientID: data.clientID,
      answer: roomAnswer
    })
  })

  socket.on('add-answer', async (data) => {
    if (peerConnections.current[data.clientID]?.currentRemoteDescription === null) {
      const answer = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer.answer)
      await peerConnections.current[data.clientID]?.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    }
  })

async function callFunction() {
    const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: { mediaSource: "screen" }
    })
    console.log("Media Stream", mediaStream);
    localMediaStream.current = mediaStream;
    localVideoRef.current.srcObject = localMediaStream.current;
    console.log("Call called");
    socket.emit('call', "5e94a33d-8133-43a0-adc3-3ef44adc2b3b");
  }
```

My signaling server code is:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('join', (roomID) => {
        console.log(roomID);

        const { rooms } = socket;
        if (!Array.from(rooms).includes(roomID)) {
            socket.join(roomID);
            const rooms = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms).map(room => room[0]);
            io.emit('share-rooms', rooms.filter(room => validate(room)));
        }
    })

    socket.on('call', (roomID) => {
        let clients = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms).find(x => x[0] === roomID);
        if (clients === undefined)
            return;
        clients = clients[1];
        console.log("Clients", clients);
        clients = Array.from(clients).filter(clientID => clientID !== socket.id);
        clients.map((client) => {
            io.to(client).emit("call", {
                clientID: socket.id,
                offer: false
            });

            console.log(client);
            socket.emit("call", {
                clientID: client,
                offer: true
            })
        })
    })

    socket.on('add-offer', ({ clientID, offer }) => {
        console.log("Add offer emitted", clientID, offer);
        io.to(clientID).emit('add-offer', {
            offer: offer,
            clientID: socket.id
        });
    })

    socket.on('add-answer', (data) => {
        console.log(`Add answer`, socket.id, data);
        console.log("Rooms", Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms))
        io.to(data.clientID).emit('add-answer', {
            clientID: socket.id,
            answer: data.answer
        });
        console.log(`Sending answer to ${data.clientID} from ${socket.id}`)
    })

    socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
        socket.join(roomId)
        socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
        })
    })

    socket.on("send-ice", (data) => {
        console.log("Send ice emitted", data);
        const clientID = data.clientID;
        console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
        io.to(clientID).emit('add-iceCandidate', {
            clientID: socket.id,
            iceCandidate: data.iceCandidate
        });
    })
})
```

According to the WebRTC Internals tab, my clients are successfully exchanging the offer and answer. Also icecadndidate. But the fields have the following statuses:
ICE connection state: new
Connection state: new
Signaling state: new => have-remote-offer => stable => have-remote-offer => stable
ICE Candidate pair: (not connected)

The call takes place between 2 browsers on the same computer.

What could be the error?

I tried different versions of the implementation with different expiration dates, but the result was always that I didn't get the deleted image. Now, my implementation according to the documentation from the Webrtc website is as follows